# Dojo DateTextBox parser

Tags: парсер, календарь, dojo

Добрый день! У меня такая проблема хочу получить поле, по которому кликаешь, появляется календарик выбираешь дату и это поле заполняется. https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/DateTextBox.html (самый последний пример по ссылке)
Вот скрин моего результата

[image: Результат]

Проблема в том, что ошибок не выдает, но парсит неправильно. По щелчку календарь появляется, но неоформленный и внизу страницы. Вот куски моего кода: шаблон, где создаю элемент

```html
<div data-dojo-attach-point='changeDate' class='changeDataField'>
   <label for="calendarId">Выберите дату:</label>
   <input data-dojo-id="calendarId" type="text" name="calendar" data-dojo-            
                   type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" value="now" required="true" />

</div>
```

Вот код парсинга и добавления модулей. Парсинг происходит в функции `setDate`.

```
define("traffic/SheduleView", ["dojo/_base/declare",  "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/query",
        "dijit/_Widget", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", "dojo/window", "dojo/text!traffic/resources/SheduleView_template.html", "dojo/dom", "dojo/parser", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(declare, array, dom_construct, on, dom_style, query, _Widget, _TemplatedMixin, win, template, dom, parser, DateTextBox) {
        'use strict';

        return declare("traffic.SheduleView", [_Widget, _TemplatedMixin], {

            templateString: template,

            constructor: function() {

                this.sheduleViewShow = false;
            },

            postCreate: function() {
                console.log("postCreate");
                var obj = this;
                on(window, 'resize', function() {
                     obj.resize();
                });
            },

            setDate: function() {
                parser.parse();
                calendarId.set('value', calendarId.get('value'));
            },
```

Ну и файл html. Настройки `dojo parseOnLoad` отключен.

```
var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    parseOnLoad: false,
    packages: [
        {
            name: "traffic",
            location: "/arcgis_js_api/library/3.14/3.14/traffic_admin"
        }
    ]
};

require(["dojo/dom", "esri/map", "esri/layers/OpenStreetMapLayer", "dojo/_base/connect", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-construct", "esri/dijit/Popup", "traffic/Chosen",
                "traffic/ControlWidjet", "traffic/RouteContainer", "traffic/StationContainer","traffic/XHR", "traffic/ObjectInfo", "traffic/VehicleList", "dojo/parser", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], 
                function(dom, Map, OpenStreetMapLayer, connect, on, domConstruct, Popup, Chosen, ControlWidjet, RouteContainer, StationContainer, XHR, ObjectInfo, VehicleList, parser, DateTextBox){
```

И сам вызов функции `setDate` в html файле.

```
controlWidjet.sheduleView.setDate();
```

Не могу разобраться уже который день. Может кто поймет меня и подскажет в чем дело? Заранее спасибо!